# B2C plataform Android Reply url

Tags: android, react-native, azure-ad-b2c

i want to register this react-native app on my Azure B2C, with For authenticating users with Azure AD B2C. (3th option at the Supported account types selection)
then I try to add the Redirect Uri, with the package name and the signature hash,  but i get the error:
One or more of your reply urls is not valid.

if i register this as an Organizational app, works fine.
can some one give me an orientation about this? why i cnat add this kind of apps in B2C? or what am i doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the option to add IOS/Android is a QuickStart to allow Microsoft Authenticator integration. But it has some restrictions, the package name is used to generate the reply url, in your case it builds something that AAD doesn’t like.

Since AAD B2C doesn’t have MS Authenticator support, just use the generic Mobile/Desktop Platform and give whatever redirect uri you want.

Answer (score 1):

Native client resources need to be registered in your tenant before your application can communicate with Azure Active Directory B2C.

1. Sign in to the Azure portal.
2. Select the **Directory + subscription** filter in the top menu, and then select the directory that contains your Azure AD B2C tenant.
3. In the left menu, select **Azure AD B2C**. Or, select All services and search for and select Azure AD B2C.
4. Select **App registrations**, and then select **New registration**.
5. Enter a Name for the application. For example, nativeapp1.
6. Under Supported account types, select Accounts in any organizational directory or any identity provider.
7. Click on Add a Platform. Select **Mobile & Desktop Applications**.
8. Enter a redirect URI with a unique scheme. For example, com.onmicrosoft.contosob2c.exampleapp://oauth/redirect. There are important considerations when choosing a redirect URI:

   - **Development** For development use, you can set the redirect URI to http://localhost and Azure AD B2C will respect any port in the request. If the registered URI contains a port, Azure AD B2C will use that port only. For example, if the registered redirect URI is http://localhost, the redirect URI in the request can be http://localhost:. If the registered redirect URI is http://localhost:8080, the redirect URI in the request must be http://localhost:8080.
   - **Unique**: The scheme of the redirect URI must be unique for every application. In the example com.onmicrosoft.contosob2c.exampleapp://oauth/redirect, com.onmicrosoft.contosob2c.exampleapp is the scheme. This pattern should be followed. If two applications share the same scheme, the user is given a choice to choose an application. If the user chooses incorrectly, the sign-in fails.
   - **Complete**: The redirect URI must have a both a scheme and a path. The path must contain at least one forward slash after the domain. For example, //oauth/ works while //oauth fails. Don't include special characters in the URI, for example, underscores.
9. Under **Permissions**, select the Grant admin consent to `openid` and `offline_access` permissions check box.
10. Select **Register**.

For more information, you can visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-native-application?tabs=app-reg-ga).

Comment: Thanks you have explain very detaild how to resiter a  Mobile & Desktop Applications. BUT, i dont understand what you mean with "Native client resources need to be registered in your tenant before your application can communicate with Azure Active Directory B2C" - im trying to login with a React native app into an app registered on azure.

Comment: Ok, did you try the other steps?

Comment: I have multiple flavour of android application, when I login to one application it asks me which application I need to login and login works, but after login to first application I can not login. to other one as it redirect me to previous application, is it possible to use same URL for differet application, I just changed URL scheme in the IOS and it works, but in android it is not letting me to change the redirect URL